# How to utilize svg2tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, svg

I am trying to convert an SVG image (or a PDF image) to `TikZ` code.  I installed svg2tikz two ways, 1) as an `Inkscape` extension and 2) as a Python pip extension.

The documentation is useless. I cannot find any documentation on how to actually use `svg2tikz` either as an `Inkscape` extension or via python.

Another answer suggested using the code

```python
tikz_export.py example.svg -o example.tex
```

but when I try to use it for my problem I obtain

> ~/Downloads> python tikz_export.py DeformedContour.svg .o
> DeformedContour.tex   File "tikz_export.py", line 8
>
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I don't care how to convert either the PDF or the SVG image to `TikZ`, it just needs to be converted.

Comment: I don't know `svg2tikz` so I don't think I can help with this specific question. But why don't you just include the PDF directly or use the SVG package? What do you need the Ti*k*Z code for? It's probably going to be a mess anyways.

Comment: Maybe it's a simple mismatch of Python 2 and 3, i.e., your `python` call uses Python 2 and the code expects Python 3 or vice versa? Other than that, `svg2tikz` is not very actively maintained judging from the Github page, so you may have more luck using one of Inkscape's built-in export formats or even redoing the graphic in TikZ from scratch (which may take some time but you will learn a lot and the result may be nicer and more readable/adjustable than automatically exported code).